# why is the context of a handler the window object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var myObject = {
  items : ... //some DOM elements
  ,attachHandlers: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items.forEach(function(){
      this.addEventListener("mouseover",self.mouseOverHandler,false);
    });
  }
  ,mouseOverHandler: function(event){
      console.log(this);
  }
};

window.onload = function()
{
  myObject.attachHandlers();
}
```

Running this on chrome, When `mouseOverHandler` is called, it prints:

`Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}`

I wonder, is `addEventListener` changing my context to the `window` object? Why so?
I want the event handler added to each element I'm iterating over.

Comment: i think because your scope is the 'window' object when function is defined

Comment: no, it's not. it's context is myObject.

Comment: You didn't notice that your mouseover handler gets called even if the mouse is not over any of the items? It should also print to console more than just one time per event, hinting at the fact that you've attached multiple handlers onto `window`.

Comment: @user1555863: In the code above, `this` within `mouseOverHandler` is never `myObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jQuery, `this` inside `Array.forEach` is not what you think it is, it's the global Window, while the first argument would be the currently iterated element

```
self.items.forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", self.mouseOverHandler, false);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hBkJs/)

Also, you can pass in `this` directly as an argument to `forEach` and avoid the variable like this

```
attachHandlers: function () {
    this.items.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("mouseover", this.mouseOverHandler, false);
    }, this);
},
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hBkJs/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one thing. if I pass `this` as the second parameter to `forEach`, it would get the wrong context again, no?

Comment: @user1555863 - depends on what context you want, `this` inside the `attachHandlers` function is the parent object, while inside the event handlers callback it's the element, so passing `this` into `forEach` we're passing the object, not the element, which would still be in the first argument of `forEach`

Answer (score 1):

The reason relates to this line:

```
this.addEventListener("mouseover",self.mouseOverHandler,false);
```

In that line, `this` is the global object (which is available as `window` on browsers). That's the nature of how `forEach` works: Unless you specify a `thisArg` as the second argument to `forEach` (after the function), it uses `undefined`. In loose mode, that means that during the call to the iteration function, `this` is the global object. (In strict mode, it would mean `this` was `undefined`.)

If you meant to attach it to each element in the loop, then:

```
// Accept the arg here ------v
self.items.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", self.mouseOverHandler, false);
//  ^--- use it here
});
```

Then, `this` within `mouseOverHandler` would refer to the element, because that's a guarantee that `addEventListener` gives you. It would *not* refer to `myObject`. If you wanted it to refer to `myObject` object instead (although there's no reason to in this case), you might use `Function#bind`:

```
,attachHandlers: function(){
  var boundHandler = this.mouseOverHandler.bind(this);
  this.items.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener("mouseover",boundHandler,false);
  });
}
```

Now, within `mouseOverHandler`, `this` would refer to your `myObject` object (although again, in this case, probably no reason to do that).

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

Side note: In your quoted code, you had `addEventListner` (missing `e`) rather than `addEventListener`, I've corrected it in the examples above.